# What does the brackets in iOS assembly code refer to?

Tags: ios, assembly

```
0x11091a760 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
```

In the above line from an app I am working on, I have researched and understood some basic assembly syntax, however I cannot find what the <+0> is referring to despite having looked around for quite some time. Each instruction has one and the numbers are unique, but not predictable. What do they mean? More examples:

```
0x11091a761 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x11091a764 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
```

Thank you :)

Comment: They are byte offsets from the start of the function. Not part of the code, just a service of your disassembler. `60=+0`,`61=+1`,`64=+4` ... see the pattern? :)

Comment: Thank you @Jester you are a genius! :)

Comment: The numbers seem unpredictable because x86 instructions have wildly varying lengths.  I recommend to use GNU objdump instead, there the relationship is clarified by having the opcodes embedded in the disassembly.

Comment: @fuz Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain your answer a little more as I would like to look into it further.

Comment: @M3nd3z I don't think there is anything I can add to my comment.  What part is unclear?